# Can't download apps on iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, mac, high-sierra

So I went on the App section on my Mac's iTunes, and clicked download... asked for my AppleID, and I typed it in. But then I get red text above it saying `This action could not be completed. Try again.` Help?

OSX 10.13
iTunes 12.6.2
Yes, I know it's not the latest iTunes, but the new one doesn't have apps.

Comment: Try upgrading to 12.6.3. It was [just released](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/10/09/apple-itunes-with-app-store-included/) as a manual download - it won't appear as an update in the App Store. This update still retains the built in Apps in iTunes. This is a special release of iTunes for those that still depend on the App functionality in iTunes. It's targeted at business workflows, however.

Comment: Nice find - DL'ing it now, 12.7 was another in a line of bad decisions:/

Comment: If you already upgraded to 12.7 you might want to consider grabbing your iTunes Library back from a backup. I couldn't persuade mine to import the 12.7 lib at all [even though MacRumours said you could]

Answer (score 1):

**Apple has released iTunes 12.6.3 with the App Store which can be installed alongside the latest version of iTunes.**

Apple [released this version](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079) specially for Volume Purchase Programs users who may need to use iTunes to install apps. **However, you can get the App Store back if you install this.**

> If you've already installed a newer version of iTunes, you can download this version of iTunes on your [Mac](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33628-20170922-EF8F0FE4-9FEF-11E7-B113-91CF9A97A551/iTunes12.6.3.dmg), [PC 32-bit](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33627-20170922-EF8CB708-9FEF-11E7-8504-92CF9A97A551/iTunesSetup.exe) or [PC 64-bit](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33626-20170922-F51D3530-A003-11E7-8324-03D19A97A551/iTunes64Setup.exe)* and run the installer. After installation is complete, you can continue to deploy apps with iTunes.

Also, this "special" version of iTunes includes compatibility with iOS 11, iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus, and iPhone X and supports both Windows and Mac.