# Can I get an older version of iTunes to get the App Store back?

Tags: ios, itunes, mac, windows

The latest version of iTunes for Mac removes the App Store which I often use to sync my apps onto my iOS devices.

[image]

Even though Apple encourages users to use the iOS App Store to manage apps, ...

> Apps for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch are now exclusively available in the new App Store for iOS. And the new App Store makes it easy to get, update, and redownload apps—all without a Mac or PC.

... I personally prefer to use my Mac's iTunes to manage apps. As such, is there any way I can get the previous version of iTunes back?

Comment: Related post are https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298307/how-do-i-backup-and-restore-my-ipa-app-backups-in-itunes-12-7 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298391/how-do-i-download-an-ios-app-ipa-file-to-my-mac-after-itunes-12-7-update

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, Apple has released iTunes 12.6.3 which can be installed alongside the latest version of iTunes.**

Apple [released this version](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079) specially for Volume Purchase Programs users who may need to use iTunes to install apps. **However, regular users can get this version too, if you want to get the App Store back.**

> If you've already installed a newer version of iTunes, you can download this version of iTunes on your [Mac](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33628-20170922-EF8F0FE4-9FEF-11E7-B113-91CF9A97A551/iTunes12.6.3.dmg), [PC 32-bit](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33627-20170922-EF8CB708-9FEF-11E7-8504-92CF9A97A551/iTunesSetup.exe) or [PC 64-bit](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33626-20170922-F51D3530-A003-11E7-8324-03D19A97A551/iTunes64Setup.exe)* and run the installer. After installation is complete, you can continue to deploy apps with iTunes.

Also, this "special" version of iTunes includes compatibility with iOS 11, iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus, and iPhone X and supports both Windows and Mac.

Comment: Does this perhaps fix the problem from this post? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301568/cant-download-apps-on-itunes

Comment: @bmike I suppose they're different problems with a similar solution.

Comment: Figured you might get a good answer to that one.

Comment: @bmike Should I delete this post and answer that instead?

Comment: Not at all - I thought yours was a dupe - but it's really not. +1 and thanks for asking. I'd answer the other as you see fit. Having the links in the comments will provide great help on the sidebar for all the posts.